# Route/Forward all traffic through device

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ethernet, forwarding

I am creating a DYI for my home, which will be a simple security gateway(testing only). I am trying to figure out how to forward or route all traffic through the security gateway:

- It will be wired and sit behind the router.
- One NIC will be used
- Security Gateway will be running ClearOS (CentOS)
- Purpose is to scan all network traffic / Content filtering.

Diagram (Both security gateway and PC are on same side as Modem/Router)

```
Modem/Router--->security gateway
|
|
|
PC
```

- I have edited /etc/sysctl.conf and inserted: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1. Then reloaded sysctl -p

- Tried iptable command to forward traffic in and out. As well as using POSTROUTE

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno16777736 -j MASQUERADE
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eno16777736 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -o eno16777736 -j ACCEPT

I had thought that the GW device (192.168.40.23) would be forwarded all traffic if I created traffic from my computer and pinged the modem/router or even google.com. PCAP is not showing any traffic from my ip 192.168.40.17 to 192.168.40.23 when I ping the modem/router 192.168.40.254. Not sure why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) I could make the security gateway the default IP gateway, correct?

You could, but you do not have to. You could still use your router as a DHCP server for the devices on the other side of the security device. DHCP requests coming from the other side of the security gateway can simply be forwarded to your router without having to set up a DHCP server on the security gateway itself.

> However I would need to make sure the DHCP Server in router is off and
>   DHCP Server on Security device on, correct?

Not necessarily. You should only do this in the case where you wanted to give your security gateway a static IP and also let the security device handle DHCP for the devices you will use on your LAN, which as mentioned above, is not required.

> 2.) Create static route/IP forwarding. This should work correct?

Yes. Allow packet forwarding on the security gateway by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Uncomment the line (or add it if not present):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then run:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

You will also need to make sure that the firewall on your security gateway is allowing forwarding for the appropriate interfaces.

As for static routes, these will only be needed if you want to split your setup into multiple subnets. Since you can achieve your setup using a single subnet, you will not have to add routes. All of the routing information needed by devices on your LAN will be acquired through their DHCP requests.

Comment: awesome thanks. I think I am going to try IP forwarding. How can I test to make sure all traffic is being forwarded. Would a tcpdump or wireshark work or is that overkill?

Comment: Not at all. tcpdump is a good tool for this purpose. Pinging the router while behind the security gateway is also a simple diagnostic you can use.

Comment: does this apply to CentOS?

Comment: This did not work . No seeing nay traffic of device even with forward

Comment: If memory serves me right I am not seeing traffic because of my router which is a switch. So I ether need a man in the middle with arpspoof or some how have my device get all traffic ?

Comment: Hmm could you clarify what you mean by "my router which is a switch"?

Comment: Yes, this can apply to CentOS

Comment: Sorry I should of just said router. So in the diagram up top, there are 3 devices. With ip forward enable on security gateway (which has no router function and just a device with clearos based off centos ) , if the pc in diagram talks to internet the security gateway sees all the traffic right? That's what I am trying  accomplish. A device that is not the router that has all network traffic pass through and can scan all the traffic. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm looking back at the edits and I see now that your network diagram was changed after my original answer. The answer I have given is in the layout of your original post which was (router <=> security appliance <=> LAN). Please confirm if this layout is the correct one. If it is indeed correct, then yes, the security appliance can scan the packets passing through it.

Comment: Security appliance is a part of LAN. So router <=> Lan(pc and security appliance) so by default all of traffic goes to router currently. Security appliance has one nic so traffic  from pc to router then internet needs to go through security 1st. From other forms it sounds like I need to 1.) enable ip forward. 2.) create iptable forward in rule & iptable forward out rule. I'll try that and if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Also what you mentioned router<=>security appliance <=> lan would work but the security appliance is a single board device intended for home use, so has 1nic. I do see the confusion and I apologize.

Comment: No sweat. Forget about packet forwarding then. Just put the interface of the single NIC of the security appliance into promiscuous mode and you will be able to sniff all of the packets moving across your LAN.